# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getlogger'

Tags: python, module, python-import

When trying to get a logger object from the Python logging module:

```
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getlogger("logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.propagate = True
```

I encountered the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/train_net_step.py", line 22, in <module>
    import utils.net as net_utils
  File ~/lib/utils/net.py", line 12, in <module>
    logger = logging.getlogger(__name__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getlogger'
```

Comment: Your code is using the same spelling as the one in the solution, so one of the two has to be wrong, no?

Comment: @AMC yes, thank you for catching that.  I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Function names are case-sensitive.

```
logging.getlogger()
```

is differernt than

```
logging.getLogger() (the correct function name)
```

Using the correct, case sensative function call successfully initialized the logger object.

Answer (score 2):

In my case my script unfortunately had the name `logging.py`
The statement `using logging` then did not use the library I wanted but my script instead.
After renaming it to `logging_test.py` the error message disappeared.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I was getting conflicts because of a script called `token.py` in my project.